# EF Core set column on adding value of child property

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.0

I have a Link and Content, News entities.

```
**Link**: Id, Url, RowId, Discriminator
**Content**: Id, Text, Link
**News**: Id, Date, Text, Link
```

When I adding new Content or News I want automatically set RowId to inserted Id.
That's need to correctry resolve entity by Link.Url

So if I have Link.Discriminator and Link.RowId I can for sure determine which entity (Content or News) by Id I need.

Help me to resolve this.

Comment: have you tried for example to compute the url hash and assign it explicitly to the Link Id ?

Comment: Not sure if the question is about assigning Content/News => RowId to Link.RowId or question is how to load related data Content/News based on RowId and Discriminator.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand it this should be approximately what you're after.

```
public void AddContent(string Text, string Link)
{
    var content = new Content {
        Text = Text,
        Link = Link
        };

    //The id is collected when you add the Entity to the context
    dbContext.SaveChanges();

    dbContext.Link.Add(new Link {
        Url = <whatever>,
        RowId = content.Id,
        Discriminator = "Content"
    });

    dbContext.SaveChanges();
}
```